# regex doesnt work

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex only text space accepted and maximum 35 character.

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]*.{1,35}$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I understand you right, here's what you need

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,35}$
```

- `[a-zA-Z\s]`: whichever characters that is a letter or a space (newlines included, you might want to change that out: the `\s` is what you could replace with )

#### The problem with your regex

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]*.{1,35}$
```

- `*` means 0 times or more the pattern that I wrote before. In this case, `[a-zA-Z\s]`.
- `.` means everything except `\n` (a newline). And it was *this* pattern that *had* to be repeated at least once, and at the most, 35 times.

Comment: yes, that dot was causing problem I guess. thank you for your help!

Comment: Not only the dot, but the * aswell, as this causes the group to repeat 0 or more times, but what you actually want is the range.

Comment: I tried without * before actually, thats why I said that but you are right in case of your point of view.

Comment: Yes, the dot means *whichever characters except a new line (\n)*. So, it was this "pattern" that could be repeated 1-35 times. The `*` means ) or more. So, you could have as many letters/spaces as you wanted (`[a-zA-Z\s]`)